# Remember filled values while navigation in vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, navigation, uinavigationbar, vue-router

I have a small and probably simple question but will be happy to get your response.

I use a Vue router. I have a few nav tabs: Home and Configuration.

I filled some fields on the "Configuration" page (I don't save my changes) and navigate to "Home" and again to "Configuration" pages. As result, all my unsaved data have been deleted and I got my default values.

If there is some way to keep unsaved data when I back to the "Configuration" page?
King regards!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `beforeRouteLeave` hook to save the data in Vuex store. Here's the example.

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
   //Assuming you're storing your data in `configData`

   store.dispatch('saveConfigData', configData)
   //You can create a action (saveConfigData) in your store.
  }
```

Then when component mounts, you can use this data from store via getter to set in page/input fields.

```
mounted() {
this.data = <datafromstore>
}
```

And you can clear your store values for config data once config form is submitted successfully.